# Read function on a Bluetooth BLE device in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the flutter_blue_plus library when communicating with a Bluetooth BLE device in Flutter.
I think communicating with BLE devices is a little different from other bluetooth and serial usb communication.

How can I listen to the device via flutter_blue_plus. How can I run the read function? I did a lot of research on the internet but could not find a solution.

```
List<BluetoothService> services = await selecteddevice!.discoverServices();
                  BluetoothService lastservice = services.last;
                  BluetoothCharacteristic lastCharacterist = lastservice.characteristics.last;

                  lastCharacterist.write(Uint8List.fromList([0xFF,0x02,0x24,0x00]),withoutResponse: true);
```

I am using the above code for the write function. but I'm not sure if it's correct? I am new to this library. I will be glad if you help. If there is another library you can recommend, I can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

flutter_blue_plus comes with an excellent [usage page](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus#usage) containing examples of how to scan, connect and read/write characteristics.

Scanning for devices is as simple as using `startScan` and listen to the `scanResults`:

```
// Start scanning
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

// Listen to scan results
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // do something with scan results
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
});

// Stop scanning
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```

Reading and writing can be done after discovering the services and characteristics of the device:

```
// Reads all characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await c.read();
    print(value);
}

// Writes to a characteristic
await c.write([0x12, 0x34])
```

Following all the steps of the usage page should get you started

Comment: I have read this page many times already. But like in other bluetooth libraries, I couldn't find anything like automatic listening after making the connection. Also, when I read with the BluetoothCharacteristic.read() function, I can't get the value I should get.

Comment: @KürşatŞayhan Automatic listening is covered in the paragraph [Set notifications and listen to changes](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus#set-notifications-and-listen-to-changes). But this only works if the characteristics supports it. Please [edit] your question and add an example of what you received and what you expect to receive